# I need to remove the border color gradient around the clusters in heatmap drawn using deck.gl

Tags: heatmap, deck.gl

I'm drawing a heatmap on top of Google Maps based on the signal strength of nodes using deck.gl where color ranges from red(stands for lowest signal strength) to yellow to green(stands for highest signal strength).

The problem I'm facing is that I need to remove the border gradient which is formed as per the normal behavior of heatmap

[represents individual nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0DDo.png)

[represents cluster of nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfoNp.png)

I would also like to know if this is even possible using deck.gl.

Here's the portion of the code I used for heatmap genaration:

```
this.heatmap = [
      new HeatmapLayer({
        data,
        id: 'heatmap-layer',
        weightMin: 1,
        weightMax: 3,
        pickable: false,
        getPosition: d => [d.longitude, d.latitude],
        getWeight: d => d.signalStrength,
        intensityThreshold: 1,
        colorRange: [
          [173, 221, 142],
          [247, 252, 185],
          [240, 59, 32]],
        colorDomain: [1, 3],
        aggregation: 'MEAN'
      })
    ];
    const googleMapsOverlay = new GoogleMapsOverlay({
      layers: this.heatmap
    });
    googleMapsOverlay.setMap(this.map);
```